# Java: generate all number combitations to a bound

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers

I have the digits `1 3 5 7` and `9` (odds)what I want is a method type `long[]` that takes as parameter `int` digits

the digits paremater is supposed to be the maximum digits that the number could have.

this method is suppose to add all the possible combinations with `1 3 5 7` and `9` to the array.

What I've done so far:

Figured out the size of the array

```
int size = 0
 for(int i = 0; i < digits; i++){
        size += (int) Math.pow(5,i+1);
```

I've tried many for-loops but none of them seem to work.

The goal of this is that i'm trying to find some sort of a prime number and making this table will make my program a lot faster.

Comment: Just to be clear- there are prime numbers that contain even digits, in places other than the 1's place. Ex: 23. So you're not looking for all combinations of the digits 1,3,5,7,9 as a way to find *all* prime numbers in a range, right?

Comment: Looks like a [Project Euler problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=35) to me. If it's that, you don't need to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly i think this might work. Maybe there is a cleaner way, it's been a while since i worked in JAVA.

```
long[] expand(int digits) {
    int[] a = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    long[] b = long[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){b[i] = a[i];}        
    int it_left = digits;
    while(it_left > 0) {
        it_left--;
        long[] c = long[(b.length()*5)];
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            long tmp = a[i]*Math.pow(10, (digits-it_left));
            for(int j=0; j<b.length(); j++){
                c[(i*b.length())+j] = tmp + b[j];
            }
        }
        b = long[c.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<c.length(); i++){
            b[i]=c[i];
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```